# google places API parsing to javascript

Tags: jquery, json, rest, google-api

I have a google API URL that is has the json i wish to output on my page.

the URL including id and key

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=122&key=123-mg
```

now I want to print out in `div id myoutput` the following data

```
 "reviews" : [
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Justine OBRIEN",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/104177669626132953795/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-s6AzNe5Qcco/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAFTE/NvVzCuI-jMI/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "2 months ago",
            "text" : "Fabulous location. Wonderful warm welcoming reception. Excellent unique living Google wall entry. Sensational helpful kind people. Easy fast efficient help online plus with appointment on site. Super company always progressive plus innovative products and services for all businesses. Go Google Australia. Shine on! ",
            "time" : 1474966415
         },
```

what I have tried so far

```
<div id="myoutput"></div>

            <script>
                (function() {
                    var myobject = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=AIzaSyCUc3pmryE8WMd7niIrHIN7cq_6ZUyI-mg";
                    $.getJSON( myobject, {

                        format: "json"
                    })
                            .done(function( data ) {
                                $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                                    $( "<p>" ).attr( "author_name", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#myoutpu" );
                                    if ( i === 3 ) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                })();
            </script>
```

and

```
<script>
                (function() {
                    var myobject = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=AIzaSyCUc3pmryE8WMd7niIrHIN7cq_6ZUyI-mg";
                    $.getJSON( myobject, {
                        format: "json"
                    })

                    print myobject.dumps([s['formatted_address'] for s in result['results']], indent=2)
                    myobject["address_components"].long_name

                })();
            </script>
```

How ever I can't see to get `author_name` printed out?

Comment: Delete your key from the code example, and change it.

Comment: its not my key but i will so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems to be blocked by CORS in this case, so you can use the places library like so:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.getDetails({
    placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
  }, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for(var i=0; i <= place.reviews.length; i++) {
        console.log(place.reviews[i]);
      }
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

The `map` div is there just for the service to function. The loop is where you are shown all the reviews objects one by one. There you can do what you need with the result.
Also, you can remove the `&callback=initMap` from the link and run the function when you need it.

Comment: Hmmi understand, ill try and get this working and see what appends. thanks ill accept if i get it working

Comment: It's basically the same thing, you just use a function that is normal to google maps API. If you struggle with it I'm glad to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, ill get back to you soon (20 mins)

Comment: This looks great, how could i pull the individual objects such as author_name in html ?

Comment: Sure, in the loop just `append(place.reviews[i].author_name);`. The `reviews` item is an array so you need the `[i]` but the individual review is an object so select what element you need with `.author_name`, `.author_link` etc. Just run my function and check your inspector's console. You should have a the array set there.

Comment: Perfect and +1 for extra help